# http.get data and change css from this data Ionic 3

Tags: jquery, css, angular, http, ionic-framework

I am having some troubles to achieve the desired behaviour. My Idea is that on the moment I recieve the data from a http.get(), I subscribe to the method and I apply a css modifications to this data.  The problem is that I think is called before get the data, so the result is no success.

I let you here a plunker with what is my idea. This plunker get the data from a local array, so no problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/40pjd9t8rVTMG2k9XZnz?p=preview

my code is the following:

```
 constructor(
   public navCtrl    : NavController,
   public navParams  : NavParams,
   public http       : Http,
   public modalCtrl  : ModalController,) {
    // Get info of Excursions
    this.http.get('assets/excursions.json').map(res => res.json().excursions)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.excursions = data;
          let items = $(".excursion-item");
          let time = 500; 
          let timeUnit = `ms`;  

          items.each(function(index){
             $(this).css({
                  'animation-delay' : (1+index) * time + timeUnit
             });
          });
        });

}
```

And the view where I do this:

```
<ion-card no-padding  class="excursion-item animated fadeInLeft" *ngFor="let excursion of excursions; let i = index;" [id]="i" > <p> Test </p> </ion-card>
```

As I said, I suppose that my problem is to do not apply the animation-delay on the correct moment.

Thank you.

Comment: At a quick glance the code you have above seems to be in the right place for it to work. What is happening? Do you see an error in the console? Does it just not animate?

Comment: Hello @DeborahK, yes, the elements got animations, but the delay is not applied. All of them got the SlideInLeft at the same time.

Comment: What browser are you in? In the plunkr you supplied they come in one at a time in Chrome.

Comment: Hello again, the problem is already solved. The fact was the animation trigger must be executed once everything is load, so on ionVieWillEnter trigger correctly the animation. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animations may be out of place in your constructor - they might be firing too early in relation to when `$(".excursion-item")` is available. I would try setting your animations in an `ionViewWillEnter` function to delay the CSS change until the page is ready.

Comment: Perfect! That was the solution, it works like a charm now. Thank you so much!